# Do these phrases have different meanings?

Tags: meaning

My question is very simple, the phrases

*Important notes about productivity*

*important notes for productivity*

have different meanings?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the two sentences are actually quite different in meaning.

> important notes **about** productivity

The preposition *about* in there is used to denote the fact that we are talking about important notes that concern productivity in a certain way. That's what makes them be about productivity.

> important notes **for** productivity

Here, on the other hand, we are talking about important notes that can be used for something that can help us do things with productivity. Whatever those things are.

If you still find this confusing, please look them up in a dictionary again and I hope you will be able to clearly see the difference.

Comment: If i got an email titled with the "about" sentance, i would expect it to be telling my productivity needed to be improved in certain ways. With the second sentance, i would be expecting tips,reminders, or instructions to help have good productivity or to ensure my productivity is recorded properly or such

Comment: Yes, but *for* can also mean *about* or *regarding* Cf, e.g. [AHD def 10](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=For)

Comment: @Clare Well, only in a roundabout way. Firstly that's entirely dependent of which noun the PP is a complement of. Secondly that's only a very rough paraphrase. The *for* PP still denotes some kind of goal in such constructions. Note their example "a stickler for neatness". Paraphrasing that *for* as maning *about* is a vey rough gloss.

Answer (score -1):

The key words in these sentences which give them different meanings are [for](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/for) and [about](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/about)

> Important notes about productivity

would mean just as it says

> Important notes for productivity

would mean *Important notes **for the purpose of** productivity*